# Copyable C++ coroutine with data

Tags: c++, c++20, c++-coroutine

I have written a forward iterator that iterates over the nodes of a graph in order of a (preorder/postorder/inorder) DFS spanning tree. Since it is quite complicated compared to writing a simple DFS and calling a callback for each encountered node, I thought I could use C++20 coroutines to simplify the code of the iterator.
However, [C++20 coroutines are not copyable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58638238/can-c20-coroutines-be-copied) (much less so if they are stateful) but iterators should better be copyable!

Is there any way I could still use some coroutine-like code for my iterator?

Note: I want all iterators to iterate independently from each other. If I copy an iterator and then call `++` on it, then only the iterator should have advanced, but not its copy.

Comment: you shouldn't need to make the cororoutine copyable, the iterator should be referencing a coroutine generator that manages all of this. [example of this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/msdn-magazine/2017/october/c-from-algorithms-to-coroutines-in-c) [another example](https://blog.feabhas.com/2021/09/c20-coroutine-iterators/)

Comment: [related](https://stackoverflow.com/q/66239578/332733) and [also related](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68669992/332733)

Comment: As far as I can tell, in both examples linked in your first comment, an iterator is not independent from its copy. That is, when I call `++` on the original iterator, its copy will also have advanced. This is not what I want. I'll try to be more clear in the post above.

Comment: If I understood correctly, also in the related posts, people try and store the coroutine-handle in the iterator and then call `handle.resume()` in the iterator's `operator++`. This means, all iterators share the same global state (that of the coroutine), so they cannot iterate independently.

Comment: If you want to create a 'copy' you'd need to duplicate the generator the iterator is dependent on. You should not try to duplicate the handle because that has to live and die with the generator. Ideally you'd tear that off the container you're using even if you seed state from the existing generator. Regardless you'd need to hold onto a pointer to the generator (non-owning) if you intended to do that. Regardless you need to be able to copy state and not the coroutine.

Comment: "you need to be able to copy state and not the coroutine" - I agree with that. But, as far as I understood (please correct me if I'm wrong), C++ coroutines have **no way** to separate their state from the code (that's why their generator's copy-constructor and copy-assignment are deleted). Note how, in the answer I posted below, I **do** separate the state from the coroutine itself, which is, indeed, essential for copying the iterator.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured that, with the [Miro Knejp "goto-hack"](https://youtu.be/IAdLwUXRUvg?t=1878), something resembling copyable co-routines is possible as follows (this toy example just counts "+1" "*2" until a certain value but it illustrates the point).

(1) this is just a simple wrapper for the actual function

```cpp
template<class Func, class Data>
struct CopyableCoroutine {
  Data data;
  Func func;

  CopyableCoroutine(const Data& _data, const Func& _func): data(_data), func(_func) {}

  bool done() const { return data.done(); }

  template<class... Args> decltype(auto) operator()(Args&&... args) {
    return func(data, std::forward<Args>(args)...);
  }
};
```

(2) this is where the magic happens

```cpp
struct my_stack {
  int n;
  int next_label_idx = 0;
  bool done() const { return n > 30; }
};

int wierd_count(my_stack& coro_data) {
  static constexpr void* jump_table[] = {&&beginning, &&before_add, &&after_add, &&the_end};
  goto* jump_table[coro_data.next_label_idx];
beginning:
  while(coro_data.n <= 32) {
    coro_data.next_label_idx = 1;
    return coro_data.n;
before_add:
    coro_data.next_label_idx = 2;
    ++coro_data.n;  // odd steps: add one
    return coro_data.n;
after_add:
    coro_data.next_label_idx = 3;
    coro_data.n *= 2; // even steps: multiply 2
  }
the_end:
  return -1;
}
```

play with it [here](https://godbolt.org/z/j7rKerdxG).

NOTE:  unfortunately, this "dirty hack" requires some extra work and I would be super happy if that could be avoided somehow. I'd really love to see C++ native coroutines that can be copied if the user promises that its stack is copyable.